# Trying to make a gif in Fortran using do loops and open file

Tags: fortran

I'm currently trying to make a gif with Fortran but I'm still a beginner and I don't know exactly how to do it. My program is on the phase portrait of a disturbed pendulum and I want to make a gif out of it. Here is my code:

```
integer :: i,j,ij
real(kind=8) :: x,xp,xpp,a,dt,eps,t,pii
character*12 :: filename
dt=0.01
pii=3.14159265359
eps=1
x=modulo((-pii+2*pii)/2+pii,2*pii)-pii
xp=0
t=0
do i=1,300
    x=modulo((-pii+2*i*pii)/(2*i)+pii,2*pii)-pii
    xp=0
    t=0
    write(filename,'("graphespoincare",i2.2,"txt")')i
    ij=30+i
    open(unit=ij,file=filename,form='unformatted',status='replace',action='readwrite')

    do j=1,300         !Euler
        a=x
        xpp=acc(a,t)   !acceleration function
        xp=xp+xpp*dt
        x=x+xp*dt
        t=t+dt
        write(ij,*) x,xp,t,en(x,xp)
    enddo
    close(ij)
enddo
```

Now the problem is when I use it I don't get any file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've declared `filename` of length 12, rather than the length 20 required.  You're also trying to write formatted output to an formatted connection.  So, if you get _any_ messages from running the program, or compiling, please show them.

Comment: Oh you're right thank you. I changed that to 20 just now but I get only one empty file: graphespoincare01.txt.

Comment: @francescalus I think you mean "You're also trying to write formatted output to an UNformatted connection"? Assuming the compete program is the above with and End statement that would explain the behaviour the poster is reporting, but a complete program and error messages would make it so much easier to diagnose.

Comment: Open the file with access="stream" please and use write(ij) instead of write(ij,*)

Comment: @FrancoisJacq Why access="stream" ? Do gifs require this?

Comment: @Francois Jacq Thank you, it works better now but I get only the first 100 files.

Comment: . And I also changed the form of the files thanks to @Francescalus help.

Comment: Could you please, please show the code you are currently using and any error messages that are being produced - how you are compiling it might be useful as well.

Comment: @IanBush now everything is perfect I get all the files.

Comment: @Ian Bush access=Stream avoids to put classical records length into the file (usualy at the beginning and at the end of each record). A gif file does not contain such record lengths

Comment: @Skalli Omar you get only 99 files because of the format I2.2 you have used when creating the file name. a format I0 should be better.